# I am getting the below errors and am not getting an idea to resolve it. Can anyone help me to rectify it

Tags: android

The below i have shown you the Manifest.Xml, MainActivityClass and also added the Logcat Errors.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lockscreen"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name="com.example.lockscreen.LockControlWidgetProvider" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.lockscreen.LockMainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.lockscreen.LockControlService"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_lock_control_service" >
        </activity>
        <service 
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name="LockControlService"
            ></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my code follows:

**LockMainActivity.Java**

```
public class LockMainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.lock_main);
        final Intent unlockIntent = createIntent(context,appWidgetIds);
        unlockIntent.putExtra(LockControlWidgetProvider.EXTRA_LOCK_ACTIVATED, false);
        unlockIntent.setAction(LockControlWidgetProvider.ACTION_UNLOCK);
        final PendingIntent pendingUnlockIntent = createPendingIntent(context, unlockIntent);

        // Lock Intent

        final Intent lockIntent = createIntent(context, appWidgetIds);
        lockIntent.putExtra(LockControlWidgetProvider.EXTRA_LOCK_ACTIVATED, true);
        lockIntent.setAction(LockControlWidgetProvider.ACTION_LOCK);
        final PendingIntent pendingLockIntent = createPendingIntent(context, lockIntent);

        // Status Intent
        final Intent statusIntent = createIntent(context, appWidgetIds);
        statusIntent.setAction(LockControlWidgetProvider.ACTION_LOCK);
        final PendingIntent pendingStatusIntent = createPendingIntent(context, statusIntent);

        //bind click

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.txtOn, pendingLockIntent);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.txtOff, pendingUnlockIntent);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_root, pendingStatusIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
        context.startService(statusIntent);
    }
    private Intent createIntent(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent updateIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
                 LockControlWidgetProvider.class);
                 updateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,
                 appWidgetIds);
                 return updateIntent;
    }
    private PendingIntent createPendingIntent(Context context,
            Intent updateIntent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                 context.getApplicationContext(), 0, updateIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                 return pendingIntent;
    }
}
```

Below the error follows:

**Logcat**

> 07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): Process: com.example.lockscreen, PID: 2104
>       07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lockscreen/com.example.lockscreen.LockMainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.lockscreen.LockMainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
>       07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
>       07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>       07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>       07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>       07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>       07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>       07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>       07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>       07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>       07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.lockscreen.LockMainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
>       07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
>       07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
>       07-18 20:48:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     ... 11 more
>       07-18 20:53:46.984: I/Process(2104): Sending signal. PID: 2104 SIG: 9

Comment: Also post your code..

Comment: show your LockMainActivity class

Comment: @ajkishore does your `lockscreen` class extend activty? Also is it defined in your manifest?

Comment: Can we see your manifest? I think there is problem in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because `LockMainActivity` is not an `Activity`. You cannot just call it an Activity- it needs to extend the `Activity` class.

Somewhere either in your manifest (in an `<activity>` tag) or in another Activity (with an Intent) you are trying to use `LockMainActivity` as an Activity, and thus the app is crashing.